# REGEX Question: Match regex, but exclude a specific string

Tags: regex

With the Regex `\s-\s.*:\s` I successfully match **the following**:

22/12/2015, 17:31 **- Dr. Peper:** My Message
22/12/2015, 17:01 **- Frank:** MESSAGE MA MA MA MA
asdf aysfjsfdl asdfoasdf
22/12/2015, 17:18 **- Sepp:** MESSAGE ----- XXX
22/12/2015, 17:31 **- Dr. Peper:** My Message

However, now I want to exclude the string "Dr Peper" from the matching. How can I get the following as a result?

22/12/2015, 17:31 - Dr. Peper: My Message
22/12/2015, 17:01 **- Frank:** MESSAGE MA MA MA MA
asdf aysfjsfdl asdfoasdf
22/12/2015, 17:18 **- Sepp:** MESSAGE ----- XXX
22/12/2015, 17:31 - Dr. Peper: My Message

"Sepp" and "Frank" are arbitrary strings.

> Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\s-\s.*(?<!Dr\. Peper):\s` https://regex101.com/r/llXSX4/1 or `\s-(?!\s*Dr\. Peper)\s.*:\s`

Comment: See if [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4Qu17/1) helps.

Comment: Please format your question to be easy to read and understand. Use the `{}` button in the editor toolbar to mark the code or the data to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` part of the pattern will first match until the end of the string and will then backtrack until the first `:` that can be followed by a whitespace char.

If you want to match a whitespace char and then until the first occurrence of `:`, I would suggest using a negated character class `[^:\r\n]*` instead matching any char except a `:` or a newline.

To match the names except Dr. Peper, you could use a negative lookahead to assert what follows is not 0+ whitespace chars an Dr. Peper:

```
\s-(?!\s*Dr\. Peper:)\s[^:\r\n]*:\s
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i2mdfd/1)